# Fetching previous revisions of multiple files via Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

While trying to import some Android projects into Eclipse, I have noticed that every file in the project is 0 bytes after they are imported.  These projects are stored on Drive, so there is some chance of reverting them back to the previous version.

Reverting files to previous versions is easy to do when you've got a few files - you simply do it through a browser.  However, I have hundreds of files and I need to fetch one revision back for each.  I have been able to download a number of files by hand thus far, but there has to be a better way.

I have asked Google support and actually got a response back, but it's clear that there is no built-in functionality to do this.  So I have started looking at the Drive API but I can see that there might be a bit of a learning curve.

Wondering if anyone has run into this before? Ideally I would like to identify one folder and for each file underneath, fetch the last version of the file.  If anyone has a good approach for this, I would love to hear it.

thanks!

Comment: When you say "fetch the last version of the file." , do you mean "last version" or "last version but one"?

Comment: @Pinoyyid one version less than the current version.  For each file, the current revision is 0 bytes.  So I want to retrieve the previous revision.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudeo code to do what you want is

```
# get the id of the folder https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list
fid=file.list(q=title = 'foo')[0]
# get the children of that folder https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list
children = file.children(fid).maxresults=999
# for each child, 
for id in children.id
  # get the revisions https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/get
  revisions = file.revisions(id)
  # iterate, or take item[1] whatever works best for you, and use its downloadUrl to fetch the file
```

With each call that you make, you'll need to provide an access token. For something like this, you can generate an access token using the oauth playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

You'll also need to register a project at the cloud/api console https://code.google.com/apis/console/

So ye, it's a disproportionate amount of learning to do something fairly simple. It's a few minutes work for somebody familiar with drive, and I would guess 3 days for somebody who isn't. You might want to throw it up on freelancer.com.