# Google Drive Files - Batch Manage Revision

Tags: google-drive-api, malware

I've tried to look for a solution for this, however havent been able to so I thought I'd start the a new question.

What I'm wanting to do is to revert files that have been edited on a particular date, to revert back to its previous revision.  The reason for this is because a malware was found on my computer, where it had ENCRYPTED all of my files.  Since I had the Google Drive application on my desktop running, the malware Encrypted those files and Google Drive had synced it to the cloud...So currently I have a bunch of corrupted files sitting in Google Drive.

I can go into each file to manually "manage revision" and revert it back to the working version, however this has taken me hours and hours to do, due to the amount of files.

I've done abit of reading about the Google Drive API which could possibily be used, but am no expert programmer, so I'd just like to ask if anyone has any suggestions/know of the best way to fix this problem.

Cheers,
Alfred

Comment: This answer looks somewhat relevant: fetching-previous-revisions-of-multiple-files... http://stackoverflow.com/a/26657459/2427089  
However it's just pseudocode and links to google cloud/API console, not a complete solution.
You'd also have to somehow determine the correct revision number for each file, the time/date stamp doesn't appear to be easy to get from the API.
Also, it looks like Drive keeps old revisions for at least 30 days. The web interface has a "keep forever" flag under File info - Manage versions - more actions. But I don't see where this would be accessible from the API.

Comment: The "keep forever" feature maps to the Drive API "pinned" property. See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/update

Answer (score 5):

It's not that difficult to do. I'm assuming that files were all infected (therefore edited) on the date in question, and that they haven't been edited since. If that's the case, then you can find those files using https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list with https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters specifying **modifiedDate**.

You can then retrieve the revisions feed https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/list, and I guess you're looking for the most recent revision, prior to the malware date.

You'll then fetch the content and use it to create a new file, probably in a new "unencrypted" folder. Alternatively, you could try using https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/delete to delete the encrypted revision, thus exposing the unencrypted revision prior to it. NB I haven't tried this approach yet.

If you've never created a Drive App before, you're in for a lot of fun. Budget 2-3 days to do the reading and get it working. As a skeleton, you might want to look at https://github.com/pinoyyid/drive-untrash. This was something I wrote to quickly untrash all of a user's files. So a different use case, but by replacing `q=untrashed` with `q=modifiedDate=yyyy-mm-dd`, and replacing `untrash` with `get_revisions, delete top_revision`, it's not a million miles away from what you want.

**NB. kinda obvious, but make sure you have a backup copy of everything before hacking revisions.**

Answer (score 5):

We got attacked by the cerber Ransomware and it infected our Google drive.
I was able to create a Python script that uses Google Drive API to go back a rev on the drive. The code is reproduced here instructively. DO NOT use it as it is.
Please note the disclaimer at the top of the code. 
Hopefully it will get you started on a path to full recovery.

Note also that in order to use Google Drive you will have to login using the account that was infected and generate a client_secret.json file by going to https://console.developers.google.com . Put the file in the same directory as this script.

Run the script as :
%python script_name.py

```
# This file CHANGES the drive. USE IT AT YOUR OWN RISK. I'M NOT RESPONSIBLE FOR ANY LOSE.
# It removes the revisions of cerber2 encrpted files
# It also renames the file back to what it was before the cerber2 infection
# You will probably have to run it multiple times because it only removes one rev each time.
# Good luck! Hope you get back to a state you were before the infection.
#

from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os
import json

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/drive-python-quickstart.json
#SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'drive-python-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Drive API.

    Creates a Google Drive API service object and outputs the names and IDs
    for up to 10 files.
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

    results = service.files().list(
      corpus="domain",
      spaces="drive",
      pageSize=1000,
      orderBy="folder,modifiedTime desc,name",
      q= "name contains 'DECRYPT MY FILES'",
      fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)"   
        ).execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])
    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
                deleteFile = service.files().delete(fileId=item['id']).execute()
                print("file deleted " + item['name'])


    results = service.files().list(
      corpus="domain",
      spaces="drive",
      pageSize=1000,
      orderBy="folder,modifiedTime desc,name",
      #q="modifiedTime > '2016-09-04T12:00:00'",
      q= "name contains 'cerber2'",
      fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)"   
        ).execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])
    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
                details = service.files().get(
                    fileId=item['id'],
                    fields="lastModifyingUser,name").execute()
                #print(details)
                if(details['name'].endswith("cerber2")):
                    print('-------------------------File-------------------------------')
                    print(details)
                    revs = service.revisions().list(fileId=item['id'],fields="kind,revisions").execute()
                    allrev = revs['revisions']
                    print('==checking old revs==')
                    if(len(allrev) > 1):   
                        #print(json.dumps(allrev,indent=4))                    
                        lastRev = allrev[-1]
                        if(lastRev['originalFilename'].endswith("cerber2")):
                          try:
                            print("removing lastrev of file " + details['name'] + " " + lastRev['id'])   # delete the lastRev
                            revDel = service.revisions().delete(fileId=item['id'],revisionId=lastRev['id']).execute()
                            print(revDel)
                          except:
                            print("trying to remove earlier rev") # in case there are two revs with same time stamp, Google does not return the last rev as the last structure and the script fails
                            lastRev = allrev[-2]
                            if(lastRev['originalFilename'].endswith("cerber2")):
                              try:
                                print("removing lastrev of file " + details['name'] + " " + lastRev['id'])   # delete the lastRev
                                revDel = service.revisions().delete(fileId=item['id'],revisionId=lastRev['id']).execute()
                              except:
                                print("Please handle this file yourself. Unable to remove revisions " + details['name'])
                        else:
                          print("lastRev name does not seem infected " + lastRev['originalFilename'])
                          file = {'name': lastRev['originalFilename']}
                          # Rename the file.
                          updated_file = service.files().update(fileId=item['id'],body=file,fields='name').execute()
                          print("Renamed")
                    else:
                        lastRev = allrev[0]
                        print("rename " + details['name'] + " id=" + item['id'] + " to " + lastRev['originalFilename'])
                        file = {'name': lastRev['originalFilename']}
                        # Rename the file.
                        updated_file = service.files().update(fileId=item['id'],body=file,fields='name').execute()
                        print("Renamed")






if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


#set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8  : You may need to set this in case file names have chars that cannot be printed on the console
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used this script as a base to clean the drive after a Zepto Ransomware infection. My script : https://bitbucket.org/snippets/cyclick/EBbEG

Comment: Here's the steps to create `client_secret.json` if anyone gets lost in the console: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer just now. Basically used the same idea back in September 2016, but in Java.
For full blog: https://www.tmns.com/cerber3-ransomware-infected/

Hope this helps someone. Ransomware sucks.

Source code:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.Revision;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.RevisionList;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class GDriveList {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Drive API Java Quickstart";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"),
            ".credentials/drive-java-quickstart");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials at
     * ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
    // Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
    // The DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY scope did not give me enough "power". Switched to "DRIVE". 

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * 
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = GDriveList.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
                clientSecrets, SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY).setAccessType("offline").build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println("Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
     * 
     * @return an authorized Drive client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a list of revisions.
     *
     * @param service
     *            Drive API service instance.
     * @param fileId
     *            ID of the file to retrieve revisions for.
     * @return List of revisions.
     */
    private static List<Revision> retrieveRevisions(Drive service, String fileId) {
        try {
            RevisionList revisions = service.revisions().list(fileId).execute();
            return revisions.getRevisions();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Rename a file.
     *
     * @param service
     *            Drive API service instance.
     * @param fileId
     *            ID of the file to rename.
     * @param newTitle
     *            New title for the file.
     * @return Updated file metadata if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
     */
    private static File renameFile(Drive service, String fileId, String newTitle) {
        try {
            File file = new File();
            file.setName(newTitle);

            // Rename the file.
            Files.Update updateRequest = service.files().update(fileId, file);
            updateRequest.setFields("name");

            File updatedFile = updateRequest.execute();
            return updatedFile;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Drive service = getDriveService();

        String fileId;
        String revisionId;
        String currentFilename = "";
        String originalFilename = "";
        String nonCerberName = "";
        String cerberFilename = "";
        boolean moreThanOneFilename = false;

        // Get files in batches of 500.
        FileList result = service.files().list()
                .setPageSize(500)
                .setQ("name contains '.cerber3'")
                .setSpaces("drive")
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute();
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
        if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No files found."); // And this would be a good
                                                    // thing!
        } else {
            // Decided to put my output in a format that I could later easily
            // paste into Excel
            // So these are the headers of my CSV file.
            // Just remember to start this code with the following command:
            // gradle -q run >> output.csv
            System.out.println("Filenum, Filename, fileId, revisionId, cerberFilename, originalFilename");
            int filenum = 0;
            String realFilename = "";
            String deleteVersionId = "";
            String renameVersionId = "";
            String renameFilename = "";
            for (File file : files) {
                // Note: don't put \n at the end. There will be more stuff
                // printed later on.
                System.out.printf("%s, %s, %s, ", ++filenum, file.getName(), file.getId());
                // Try to get a bit more info in a separate call.
                fileId = file.getId();
                cerberFilename = file.getName();
                moreThanOneFilename = false;

                List<Revision> revisions = retrieveRevisions(service, fileId);
                if (revisions.size() != 2) {
                    // This statement will mess up the CSV-style output I'm
                    // trying to create.
                    // Talk to someone who cares...
                    System.out.println("There are " + revisions.size() + " revisions (and not 2), skipping");
                } else {
                    // Loop through all TWO revisions
                    realFilename = "";
                    for (Revision listRevision : revisions) {
                        renameVersionId = "";
                        deleteVersionId = "";
                        revisionId = listRevision.getId();

                        // OK, got the fileID, now the revisionID, now get the
                        // revision itself.
                        // Think we already had the revision? Think again. We
                        // need to retrieve it via
                        // a separate get(), since we need to tell the API to
                        // get the originalFilename
                        // in the return JSON.
                        Revision revision = service.revisions().get(fileId, revisionId).setFields("id,originalFilename")
                                .execute();
                        originalFilename = revision.getOriginalFilename();
                        if (originalFilename.indexOf(".cerber3") > -1) {
                            // Yeah, found the encrypted file, let's delete this
                            // version
                            // System.out.printf("Going to delete file,
                            // versionid, originalName: %s, %s, %s\n", fileId,
                            // revisionId, originalFilename);
                            deleteVersionId = revisionId;
                        } else {
                            // System.out.printf("Going to rename file,
                            // versionid, originalName: %s, %s, %s\n", fileId,
                            // revisionId, originalFilename);
                            renameVersionId = revisionId;
                            renameFilename = originalFilename;
                        }
                    }
                    // Looped through 2 version, now do the deleting + renaming
                    // First delete the version
                    service.revisions().delete(fileId, deleteVersionId).execute();

                    // Rename the version
                    File renamedFile = renameFile(service, fileId, renameFilename);
                    // And complete the CSV-line, started before (already
                    // printed num, filename, fileid)
                    System.out.printf(" %s, %s, %s\n", deleteVersionId, cerberFilename, renameFilename);
                }
            }
        }
        // Now let's look for the cerber "help" files...
        // These files are named either
        // @___README___@.html or @___README___@.txt or @___README___@.url 
        result = service.files().list()
                .setPageSize(500)
                .setQ("name contains '@___README___@.'")
                .setSpaces("drive")
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute();
        files = result.getFiles();
        if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No cerber files found."); // And this would be a good thing!
        } else {
            int filenum = 0;
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.printf("Going to delete file %s, %s, %s\n", ++filenum, file.getId(), file.getName());
                // .delete only works if you are the owner of the file.
                // Which, in this case, is exactly what we want.
                service.files().delete(file.getId()).execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, ransomware encrypted all my files on my PC, and because I had Google Backup & Sync installed, it pushed all the encrypted files to Google Drive.

I created this nodejs script to delete the encrypted revision and rename the files back to their original:
https://github.com/ronnyvdb/rollbackRevisionsGoogleDrive